# How to find an element that has a specific text without other inside elements

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an HTML string like this.

```
html = '<div>outer<div>inner</div></div>'
```

I want to get text from only inside of a `div` element.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath('//div[contains(.,"inner")]')
```

But this code gets not only the inner element, but also the outer element because the outer element also contains the text `inner`.

How can I find an element that contains a specific text without inner HTML tag?

I can easily get the inner element in this case by `doc.css('div > div')`, but in real case, I am not sure how many `div` tags exist. And the inner text may include more text, except for inner like:

```
html = '<div>outer<div>inner text</div></div>'
```

Comment: You can try this `doc.xpath('//div[contains(text(),"inner")]')`

Comment: So, no matter how many possible nested divs there are, you only want the outermost div's immediate text?

Comment: @theTinMan Oh, I'm terrible sorry. I thought I've written "WITH inner HTML tag.", I want to get the innermost element.